# Foundation6: Full width in nested row column

Tags: zurb-foundation

Im currently using Foundation 6.3.1 and stuck on overriding nesting column to full container width.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
<div class="row container">
  <div class="column small-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column standard">
        Standard content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row expanded">
      <div class="column full">
        Full screen width content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column standard">
        Standard content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/maca1016/pen/QgobrJ

I need the "Full screen width content" area expanded to full width of the browser window. If possible I want to achieve this through the framework. Rather not use `position: absolute;` for solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override the container's `width` declaration for this section, and force the content to be larger than it's container. I forced it with an inline style and it worked in the pen, but you may want to clean it up and add a `class` for this, or an `ID` if it is just a one off use.

```
<div class="row expanded">
  <div style="width:150%!important;" class="column full">
    Full screen width content
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJzJQv

Answer (score 0):

Is there any special reason for that `.row.container` wrapping it all?, I think the solution is clearly taking the items you need full width (the .row.expanded and its children) out of that container, without making adding anything else.

Hope this helps.